# nav links on top of each other

Tags: html, css

Okay so im building a nav and i ran into a problem they are stuck on each other.

```css
body{
   margin:0px;
 border:0px;
}

.nav-wrapper{
background-color: #34384a;
width: 100%;
height: 70px;
overflow: hidden;
margin: 0;
}
.prime-nav{

}
.prime-nav a{
 padding: 24px 30px;
 
 display: inline-block;
 border-right: 1px solid #34495E;
 border-left: 1px solid #34495E;
 overflow: hidden;
 position: fixed;
 left: 500px;

}
.prime-nav a:hover{
 background-color: #2e3242;
}
a{
 text-decoration: none;
 color: white;
 font-size: 20px;
}
```

```html
<div class="nav-wrapper">
    <div class="prime-nav">
       <a>Build Computer</a>
       <a>Other Bots</a>
    </div>

</div>
```

I want the nav items to stick in the middle so how would i fix this without removing them from the middle.

Answer (score 1):

Thanks everyone for the help i fixed my own problem by adding text-align: center;

Answer (score 0):

`float: left;` Is what you're looking for, I believe.

```css
body{
  margin:0px;
  border:0px;
}

.nav-wrapper{
  background-color: #34384a;
  width: 100%;
  height: 70px;
  overflow: hidden;
  margin: 0;
}

.prime-nav{
  left: 500px;
}

.prime-nav a{
  padding: 24px 30px;
  margin: 5px;
  display: inline-block;
  border-right: 1px solid #34495E;
  border-left: 1px solid #34495E;
  overflow: hidden;
  float: left;
  left: 500px;
}

.prime-nav a:hover{
  background-color: #2e3242;
}

a{
  text-decoration: none;
  color: white;
  font-size: 20px;
}
```

```html
<div class="nav-wrapper">
    <div class="prime-nav">
       <a>Build Computer</a>
       <a>Other Bots</a>
    </div>
</div>
```

Comment: i already had float: left; on there i dont think that's the problem

Comment: @dropletgamb Well, that's not reflected by the code you posted. Something more accurate would help you to get a better answer.